# PHP convert Array to Object

Tags: php

var_dump($response);

outputs:

```
 array(1) { ["metafields"]=> array(1) { [13]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> int(32616923206) ["namespace"]=> string(7) "ly26638" } } }
 array(1) { ["metafields"]=> array(1) { [13]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> int(32641864774) ["namespace"]=> string(7) "ly26638" } } }
```

how can I convert $response to an object to operate it like in the following code:

```
echo $response->metafields[0]->id;
```

I've tried the code below, but without any result :/

```
$object = json_decode(json_encode($response));
```

Comment: Your approach looks good but `$response->metafields[0]` doesn't exist. Try `$response->metafields[13]`.

Comment: why .... just `(object) $array;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access your "metafields's id" like `$response->metafields[13][id]` then you need to cast your response array to object.

Ex.

```
$response = (object) array(
    'metafields' => array(
            '13' => (object) array(
                    'id' => 32616923206,
                    'namespace' => "ly26638"
                )
        )
);
```

Then you can use syntax like `$response->metafields[13]->id` to access the "id" value.

Answer (score 1):

If you make an object with `(object) $response`, the child elements will still be arrays. Then you could do

```
$response->metafields[13][id]
```

If you want the object notation through the whole chain you need something like the function sandip has provided.

But why not just make this call:

```
$response[metafields][13][id]
```

Comment: ok, but how I can access only the second metafield ? every metafield has got index of 13 now, cause previously they were filtered.

Comment: That must be the second parameter in the response array. Try `$response[1]['metafields'][13]['id']`. Change the first parameter accordingly.

Comment: I've looped all the values from Array to my XML:

`foreach ($response->metafields as $meta) {
echo "<designation><![CDATA[".$meta->value."]]></designation>";
}`

it solved my problem, thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't find the member of an object by '[]'.

The '[]' is for arrays, and the '->' is for objects.

So the reason for the blank output is: **metafields[0]**.

The code below is wrong:

```
echo $response->metafields[0]->id;
```

So you should change the key of the array, **the key of an array should not be a pure number**.

I tried to change the key to 'a13', and with the code of:

```
echo $response->metafields->a13->id;
```

I got "32616923206".

That's all. O(∩_∩)O~